# How to interpret "extra" in Python documentation

Tags: python

In the documentation the following line is given to describe how to initiate a class object

```
class xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)
```

Under that it there's a line that says

> extra contains additional attributes, given as keyword arguments.

I've been experimenting but I am not certain as what this means exactly. For instance I would like to add the **text** attribute but it's not working correctly. My argument seems to be going to the **attrib** attribute instead.

Here is so sample code to highlight my issue

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.Element('Level 0',text = 'test text')
>>> tree.attrib #This should be empty
{'text': 'test text'}
>>> tree.text #test text should be here
>>>
```

Below is a link to the documentation for reference.

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects

Comment: You need to show the code that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is entirely correct. XML tag attributes are stored in the `Element.attrib` structure.

When you then output the ElementTree structure to XML, the `.attrib` values will be used to generate XML attributes:

```
>>> elem = ET.Element('Level0', text='test text')
>>> ET.tostring(elem)
'<Level0 text="test text" />'
```

The `**keywords` syntax in function signatures capture additional keyword arguments to the function call; you can pass in a explicit dictionary *or* you can use keyword arguments to define the attributes. See the [function definitions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).

The following two forms are thus equivalent (for `ElementTree.Element()` calls):

```
ET.Element('Level0', text='test text')

ET.Element('Level0', {'text': 'test text'})
```

Comment: So I guess my question is what does the **extra mean?

Comment: You mean the syntax `**`? That is a catch-all keyword argument syntax.

Comment: I don't mean to be a bother but could you provide an example of correct use of the keyword argument syntax? or a link to how to use it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @canyon289 That's a "read the official tutorial front to back" kind of question. Which you should do before asking about syntax on SO, since it's an obvious reference source for this information. (This also makes your question problematic since it seems to be asking about a given application of the syntax instead of the syntax itself.)

Comment: I understand now, I was confusing the XML attributes with Python class attributes. Thank you for clearing this up!